# Sending Push Notifications with Parse Server Cloud Code using content-available not working

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-cloud-code, parse-server

I am trying this approach to send push notifications from **cloud code** using **Parse Server** push adapter. The notifications is delivered successfully but the problem is how to use the 'content-available' flag. I'm not sure if i am using the flag the right way because the app is not being awaking when the notifications arrives as it should be.

This is the code:

```
Parse.Push.send({
   where: query,
    data: {
      alert: 'One more test 1',
      badge: 1,
      sound: 'default',
      content_available: 1
   }

}, { useMasterKey: true });
```

Again, the notifications arrives but the 'content-available' flag is not working. is anyone using this approach to send push notifications? Where should i put the 'content-available'?

Thank you all!

Comment: When content-available is given the value 1 application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler: is called. More details: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i got it! It's easier than i thought.

This would be the correct code:

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
        alert: 'One more test 1',
        badge: 1,
        sound: 'default',
        objectId: user.id,
        'content-available': 1

    }

}, { useMasterKey: true });
```

The 'content-available' flag should be separated using dash ("-") and the entire phrase between quotes.

And that's it! Hope this could help someone struggling with this like i was.

Have a great code!

Comment: Could this be used to send a push to a specific user?

Comment: It is actually for send push notifications to an specific user. Just replace user.id with the objectId of the user.

Comment: is it required to send specific data when sending a push notification? can i just send a message object inside data? and nothing more?